# Force row level security in postgres

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I want to enforce Row-Level Security (RLS) for PostgreSQL with [Row Security Policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) for ALL users including admins and table owners:

```sql
ALTER ROLE postgres WITH NOBYPASSRLS; -- enforce for the superuser
ALTER TABLE items ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
ALTER TABLE items FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY; -- enforce RLS for table owners

CREATE POLICY never_anything_policy ON items
FOR ALL -- cannot do anything
USING (false); -- never true
```

Still I can query ALL items as user postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Superusers are always exempt from row level security. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-attributes.html) says:

> superuser status
>
> A database superuser bypasses all permission checks, except the right to log in.

And [further](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html#DDL-ROWSECURITY):

> Superusers and roles with the `BYPASSRLS` attribute always bypass the row security system when accessing a table.

There is no point in trying to keep a superuser from seeing or doing something, but that is no problem. You don't use superusers for anything but administrative tasks anyway.